# fastest way to perform divison without using / or * operator any other solution

Tags: algorithm

I'm following the Skiena's algorithm book. In chapter 1, it has gives the problem to divide a real number without using / or * operator.
I implemented that in python like this:

```
def main(dividend, divisor ):
    print "dividend : ",dividend
    print "divisor : ", divisor
    if dividend<divisor:
        print "dividend has to be greater than divisor"
        return;
    quotient=0
    sum=0
    while sum<dividend:
        sum = sum+divisor
        print "sum : ",sum
        quotient = quotient+1
        if sum>dividend:
            remainder = dividend-(sum-divisor)
            quotient=quotient-1
            print "remainder : ", remainder
    print "quotient :", quotient





    if __name__ == "__main__":
        # pass any two real number as dividend and divisor
        main(29, 3)
```

The problem also stated that you must, "find the fastest way to do it". Is there any other way to solve the problem more quickly?

Comment: consider bit shifting to divide by factors of 2

Comment: not on-topic for SO - the most efficient solution in any general computing environment is to use the available facilities to do basic computation.

Comment: "dividend has to be greater than divisor" --- dubious. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by fastest: algorithmic complexity or in general?

Comment: dividend has to be greater than divisor" because it is for real integer. by fastest it mean in general

Comment: (a) what is a "real integer" and (b) by which definition of division `4/3` is legal and `2/3` is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to write code for you, but a fast way to do this uses powers of 2 and only the addition and subtraction operators. Let's consider as an example 973 / 47. First build a table of powers of 2 times the divisor; you can do that with simple addition:

```
1:  47
2:  94
4:  188
8:  376
16: 752
32: 1504
```

Each power of 2 is just the previous power of 2 added to itself. Stop when the power of 2 exceeds the dividend. Now work backward, subtracting a power of 2 if it is less than the remaining dividend:

```
16: 973 - 752 = 221
4:  221 - 188 = 33
```

So the quotient is 16 + 4 = 20 and the remainder is 33.

This algorithm is similar to the peasant algorithm for multiplication, which I discuss at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/15/three-binary-algorithms/).